# Why does my GFCI periodically trip, especially after a few days' rain?

Tags: electrical, gfci, light-fixture, rain

I have a GFCI in my living room bath that controls a couple of lights in the basement and bedroom upstairs (weird, thats what it seems to control).

Now, every 2 or 3 weeks or so, it seems to trip and the light in the basement for won't work (thats what I use regularly so I notice) . It seems to happen mostly when it has rained, but not necessarily with the first rain. It may take a couple of days' rain to cause the trip.

I have been just switching it back on again (must have done it 50 times) and keep going. Will I run into a bigger problem at some point?

I have two lights outside that do not have any covers so rain may be leaking into it through the gaps, but they still work even if GFCI has tripped.

Any ideas to troubleshoot or find the source of the problem?

Comment: Do you have a sump pump? And if so, is it feed from the gfci?

Comment: i have a sump pump but its not fed from this gfci. it worked last night when the gfci had already tripped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is going to be nearly impossible to solve without actually being there.  My advice is to call in a licensed electrician to have a look, he'll be able to trace the lines and likely find the issue quickly.

Comment: ok, will it be a problem if I keep switching it back on until I get someone to look at it.

Comment: @codernet - potentially. It all depends on why it's tripping.

Comment: what problems can it cause, theoretically?